# C++: ::ntohs() fails on higher optimization levels

Tags: c++, linux, autoconf, automake

I have a `.cpp` file: `htonstest.cpp`. I use `g++` to compile it:

```
$ g++ -o test htonstest.cpp
```

It works, and the program `./test` works too.

But, when I use automake to compile it, has a compile error:

```
 htonstest.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: 
 htonstest.cpp:6: error：expected id-expression before ‘(’ token.
```

My OS is CentOS, gcc's version is 4.1.2 20080704, autoconf's version is 2.59, automake's version is 1.9.6.

To reproduce:

```
$ aclocal
$ autoheader
$ autoconf
$ automake -a
$ ./configure
$ make
```

ntohstest.cpp:

```
 #include <netinet/in.h>
 #include <iostream>

 int main()
 {
     short a = ::ntohs(3);
     std::cout << a << std::endl;
     std::cin.get();
     return 0;
 }
```

configure.ac:

```
 AC_PREREQ(2.59)
 AC_INIT(FULL-PACKAGE-NAME, VERSION, BUG-REPORT-ADDRESS)
 AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([htonstest.cpp])
 AC_CONFIG_HEADER([config.h])
 AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])
 # Checks for programs.
 AC_PROG_CXX

 # Checks for libraries.

 # Checks for header files.
 # AC_CHECK_HEADERS([netinet/in.h])

 # Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.

 # Checks for library functions.
 AC_CONFIG_FILES(Makefile)
 AC_OUTPUT
```

Makefile.am:

```
 bin_PROGRAMS=main
 main_SOURCES=htonstest.cpp
```

Comment: try add `using namespace std;`

Comment: @JohnTortugo: Nice guess, but no.

Comment: What resource told you to use `::ntohs`?

Comment: en, good question, I don't know too. I think there is only one reason:(old code):-).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : It'd be some code to be ported from Windows, not simply some "old code".  As far as I know, "::ntohs" is correct in Windows.

Comment: I just don't see why you'd ever use the leading `::`. It just introduces portability issues, _like this one_. Whoever used it first and told their friends to do the same needs a slap in the face.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Windows programmers are from Mars, Unix programmers are from Venus (and we have the source code, too)).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So that you don't accidentally have the name resolve to something other than what you expect?  Especially relevant for stuff like ::send.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is actually unrelated to autotools, and I was quite surprised when I tested your program.  The relevant code is in `netinet/in.h`...

```
#ifdef __OPTIMIZE__
...
# define ntohs(x) ...
...
#endif
```

The reason that the code fails under Automake is because Automake defaults to `-O2`, and when `-O2` is enabled, `ntohs()` is a macro.

### The fix

Use `ntohs(3)` instead of `::ntohs(3)`.

### The alternative fix

Add the following line after your includes:

```
#undef ntohs
```

### Documentation

The `byteorder(3)` manpage reads:

> The `htons()` function converts the unsigned short integer `hostshort` from host byte order to network byte order.

So in my opinion, it is at best *rude* for the library to define an `htons()` macro.

Comment: Oh, GREAT,THANK YOU, you tell me the reason.thanks very much.

Comment: " So in my opinion, it is at best rude for the library to define an htons() macro. "

Actually, POSIX says "The following [(htonl, htons, ntohs, nothl)] shall be declared as functions, or defined as macros, or both. If functions are declared, function prototypes shall be provided." http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/arpa_inet.h.html